# How to use a type in a union as Type Alias

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, union, type-alias

I have a type definition error - `Type 'RowProp<RowType>' is not assignable to type 'RowProp<number>'.` with the following code.

```
export type RowType = number | string;

export interface RowProp<T> {
  id: string;
  row: T;
}

export interface TableData {
  id: string;
  template?: (e: RowProp<RowType>) => JSX.Element;
}

const templateA = (e: RowProp<number>) => <div></div>;

const data: TableData = {
  id: '1',
  template: templateA
}
```

How can I fix this issue.

Comment: Use `RowProp<RowType>` instead of `RowProp<number>`?

Comment: I am trying to avoid using "e as number" in the function. And the above solution doesn't work for it.

Comment: @JulianLin The reason you get the error is because in `TableData` `row` is defined that it can be either a number or a string. But when you define the function you say that it can only be a number, which is conflicting.

Comment: How do you intend the compiler to know that `data.template?.({id: "", row: ""})` is an invalid call if `TableData`'s `template` method accepts a `RowProp<RowType>` and not a `RowProp<number>`?  Maybe you're looking for assignment narrowing? If so then `TableData` needs to be a union type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w23yrN).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  In either case you might want to [edit] to show code that uses `data`. (Please mention me via @jcalz if you reply or I won't be notified.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you might be looking for generics:

```js
export interface TableData<T extends RowType> {
    id: string;
    template?: (e: RowProp<T>) => JSX.Element;
}

const data: TableData<number> = {
    id: '1',
    template: templateA
}
```

The above passes strict compilation. By allowing `TableData` to accept a generic type parameter `T`, we can now specify what the template's `RowProp` will contain.

That said, Heretic Monkey's comment above also solves the issue.